# mysql writing variables in sql insert statements

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table called sentiments with columns Date, Positive, Negative, Neutral.

How can i write my sql query such that i can insert date values as in my code below?

i think the problem lies with %s for the datetime values because all the other %s values for the columns other than date were able to be inserted.
The code below returns a sql syntax error.

```
     for item in list_of_dates: 
     d['Period'].append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(item)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d             %H:%M:%S'))

     combined_list=zip(d['period'],d['Positive'],d['Negative'],d['Neutral'])


     with con:
       cur = con.cursor()

     for x,y,w,z in combined_list:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO sentiments(%s,%s,%s,%s) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)" 
        %("Date","Positive","Negative","Neutral",str(x),str(y),str(w),str(z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the query lies in the Values. it should have small quotations for all the %s as shown below.

```
VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')
```